# JS game loop using requestAnimationFrame - object functions are called only once

Tags: javascript, function, object

I'm sorry, I'm a complete noob at js, thought I had a grasp on the basics of object instances and functions, turns out I don't and don't know how to figure out what to do.

I've declared a GameLoop function/object like this:

```
function GameLoop() {

    window.requestAnimationFrame = 
            window.requestAnimationFrame || /* Firefox 23 / IE 10 / Chrome */
            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || /* Firefox < 23 */
            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || /* Safari */
            window.msRequestAnimationFrame || /* IE  */
            window.oRequestAnimationFrame; /* Opera */

    this.start = function() {
        this.update();
    };

    this.update = function() {
        this.processInput();
        this.updateState();
        this.updateGraphics();
        window.requestAnimationFrame(this.update);
    };

    this.processInput = function() {
        alert("pi");
    };

    this.updateState = function() {
        alert("us");
    };

    this.updateGraphics = function() {
        alert("ug");
    };  

};
```

I'm trying to run it like this:

```
$(document).ready(main);

        function main() {
            var gameLoop = new GameLoop();
            gameLoop.start();
        }
```

What happends is that each of the "processInput" "updateStaten" and "updateGraphics" functions are called once (I can see each of their alerts displayed), but then it stops and the error I get (inside Firefox's error console) is

```
Error: TypeError: this.processInput is not a function
```

pointing to the `this.processInput()` line inside the `update` function.

I just don't get why, especially since the first time around the functions are called. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is running with the wrong `this`.

`this` is set based on how you *call* the function.
When called by `requestAnimationFrame`, `this` will be `window`.

To fix this, you need to preserve `this` in a closure:

```
var self = this;
requestAnimationFrame(function() { self.processInput(); });
```

You can also use the new ES5 `bind()` function to do this for you:

```
requestAnimationFrame(this.processInput.bind(this));
```

Comment: Would it be better if `bind`'s return is cached to avoid creating a function on every iteration?

Comment: Thans that worked ok. 1 extra question pls: why must I do requestAnimationFrame(function() { self.processInput(); }); and not simply requestAnimationFrame(self.processInput); ?

Comment: @ShivanDragon: For the same reason.  It would be _called_ with the wrong `this`.